# Zend escape() function doesn't work

Tags: zend-framework, escaping, zend-view

I am doing a tutorial according to [this article](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/Zend-Framework-Action-Dynamic-Content-P487.html).
This is basic *Hello World!* example using Zend Framework.

When I am looking at the output on my browser it shows me `escape($this->title);`.
I don't get the problem. Why Zend `escape()` function don't call and read this as a text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your `.htaccess` file. Your problem is PHP short tag.
If you write this in your `.htaccess` file your output on browser will be correct:

`php_value "short_open_tag" "on"`